# Unitary operator times projection operator

Tags: linear-algebra, projection-matrices, unitary-matrices, quantum-computation

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.4262.pdf), the authors claim that for $C$ a unitary operator and $P$ a projection operator, if $CP \propto P$, then the constant of proportionality must be one. I don't see why this must be the case, can't $C$ be $\theta \cdot I$ for some $\theta$, so that the action isn't completely trivial?

Comment: Well, $\theta I$ isn't unitary for real $\theta$ where $|\theta|\neq 1$, but then I'm wondering why $C$ can't be something like $e^{i\theta} I$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion is not true, as for $C=iI$ we get $CP=iP.$ However it can be shown that the proportionality constant has absolute value equal $1.$ Indeed, assume $CP= aP.$ Let $Pv=v,$ i.e.$v\in {\rm Im}\, P.$ Hence $Cv=av.$ Since $C$ is a unitary operator then $|a|=1.$

Comment: yeah this is what I figured, but I thought maybe I was just missing something obvious... I guess what's going on here is that this paper is in quantum mechanics, so they don't care about overall phases.